# Is it Pythonic to return True and None vs True and False?

Tags: python

Has this style of coding become Pythonic?  Is it recommended by people in the Python community? I saw someone use it recently and it surprised me.

```
def is_forty_two(val):
    if val == 42:
        return True
```

It returns True or None, instead of True or False.  Because bool(None) == False, this sort of code works in most places you would want to use it.

But to me, this is obviously a very dangerous coding style.  My bug detector goes off when I see code that mixes return values and running off the end without a declared return value.  But maybe I'm wrong?  Testing this code in PyCharm I see that PyCharm doesn't flag an issue and it shows the return type of the function as "-> bool"???

When I add a return None at the end, which has doesn't change how it works, PyCharm then shows the return type as the expected "Optional[bool]".

Is it a bug (or lack of complexity in PyCharm to catch this?)

Or has this style become "acceptable" in Python?

I would write it as the obvious simpler form:

```
def is_some_test(val):
    return val == 42
```

Or if the test was more complex or maybe a string of if and else, I would use a style like this:

```py
def is_some_test(val):
    if complex_test1(val):
        return True
    if complex_test2(val):
        return True
    return False
```

I would never intentionally allow a function to return True/None instead of True/False. And as a long-time matter of coding style (From decades of C programming), any function that returns an explicit value I always structure the code so it ends with an explicit return statement as the last line of function.

Comment: No, it is not Pythonic. But I can see how this mistake would be easy to make.

Comment: I think that it's a terrible way of writing a function, despite the fact that the coder might be happy that it works in their only use case (probably `if is_forty_two(val):`). I would expect any function named "is_<something>" to return a boolean.

Comment: `pylint` warns about "inconsistent-return-statements" - another point for calling it not pythonic.

Comment: Based on the answers, I would conclude it's not pythonic, but maybe it's a "mistake" that is made more often than it should be in Python by users that don't understand the risks or the history.  Thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not Pythonic, since this violates the rule ["Explicit is better than implicit"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). As a general rule, return `True` or `False` for a method whose naming convention and apparent code indicate a boolean return value. `None` is not a substitute for `False`.

Also, consider these:

```
# As expected:
print(False is False)
# True

print(False == False)
# True

# If the result of the function is 'None', it has to be cast to 'bool'
# before comparing to 'False':
print(False is None)
# False

print(False == None)
# False

print(False is bool(None))
# True

print(False == bool(None))
# True
```

**SEE ALSO:**
Python Docs: Built-in Constants: https://docs.python.org/library/constants.html
Python Docs: Built-in Types: Truth Value Testing: https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 4):

I can't answer objectively what code is Pythonic as that can easily devolve into opinion. But, consider the statement

`print(False == None)`

Which prints false, so they are not the same. So, I don't see how they can be substituted for each other.

Comment: Very true that the two forms are not identical.  This difference is why I was surprised to see it done.  It could create subtle and obscure bugs because it could work most of the time since bool(None) does equal False.  This means all the built-in bool tests like "if is_forty_two(12)" picks the false path and would work as expected for this sort of return value. But it would fail the instant someone coded "if is_forty_two(12) == False" instead of using the pythonic "if not is_forty_two(val)" form.

Answer (score 2):

The proposed solution force the code that uses the function to manage different returns type (bool or None). Not sure what is the benefit.

I suggest adding typings (if possible) to facilitate the reading/debugging:

```py
def is_forty_two(val: int) -> bool:
    return val == 42
```

Comment: Yes to the return type hint `-> bool` but `val` does not need to be an integer.

Comment: Right. Can be anything... good catch!